# cannot load such file -- aws-sdk-elastictranscoder>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I am currently referencing code from the AWS Documentation Ruby Example [JobStatusNotificationSample.rb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/ruby-elastictranscoder-JobStatusNotificationSample.rb.html)

My error comes from the first line: `require 'aws-sdk-elastictranscoder'`

Which says that I am not able to load this file. In my code, I am already using

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'
require 'aws-sdk-sqs'
```

with no previous issues. I have tried to add in `require 'aws-sdk-core'` but that did not change the error.

It is my first time working with an AWS implementation on Ruby.

Comment: did you install the  aws-sdk-elastictranscoder gem?

Comment: Thanks, I just did! I thought that'd do the trick, but unfortunately the problem persists. No changes to the error message- which I find weird.

Answer (score 0):

I have an error below when I m using Ruby SDK gem `v3`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from test_sdk.rb:1:in `<main>'
    1: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
/home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': cannot load such file -- aws-sdk-s3 (LoadError)
```

My solution:
In your terminal install `aws-sdk`

```
gem install aws-sdk
```

Then in your ruby file `test_sdk.rb`, add these in the top of the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk-s3'
```

Then run `ruby test_sdk.rb` works for my case.

Reference link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingTheMPRubyAPI.html